# Unable to scale pdfobject element down to fit in a given frame

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, pdf

I have some problems with including an PDF on an JSF site. I'm using pdfobject (http://pdfobject.com/) but it does not work out the way I want. I can't adjust my settings for my desired outcome, where there is a unscrollable, scaled document (so that it fits the frame) shown in a frame with width = 595px & height = 842px. I tried until now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var myPDF = new PDFObject({
            url : "ls_v7.pdf",
            width: "595px",
            height: "842px",
            pdfOpenParams : {
                page: 1,
                view : 'FitB'
            }
        }).embed("pdf");
    };
</script>
[...]
<div id="pdf">
    It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web
    browser. <a href="ls_v7.pdf">Click here to download the PDF</a>
</div>
```

or also

```
<object data="ls_v7.pdf#page=1&amp;view=fitH"
type="application/pdf" width="595" height="842"> </object>
```

I think I tried most of the cases mentioned in this [document](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParams.pdf), but where not able to come up with the right solution. (The oucome is always a frame with scroll-bars & the PDF gets always shown in full size)

*Some background information:*
I first included an PDF with iFrame on a JSF page, what went very well. But the Problem is, that on IE8 (some of the client machines) does not show them. So I went to this approach, if you would suggest to try another framework/etc. I would be also very greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's best to use CSS to specify exact size of the wrapper element.

PDFObject expands the PDF to 100% width/height of the parent container, so wrap your PDF in a div then size the div using CSS.

See this example: http://pdfobject.com/examples/simplest-styled.html